# Spring Security 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am adding the http tag for security reason in my security-context.xml.

For that I have addded security name space.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

I am getting the below exception not sure why this exception is getting even if I added the name space for bean.

I have 3.0.5 spring version.

Am I missing something in this please suggest. ?
Stacktrace :

```
 SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath*:spring-security/*-context.xml]
    Offending resource: class path resource [spring-security/context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 31 in XML document from file [security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.

    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the -3.0 from the schema location as spring automatically seeks the highest version in your workspace -

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Comment: I just provided the security 3.2 and worked for me but not sure how. I have 3.0.5 Spring version in my POM.xml